# How to use NSCoding protocol with an enum?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, nscoding

i have this enum:

```
typedef types {
    HBIntineraryTypeVisited = 0,
    HBIntineraryTypeUnvisited,
    HBIntineraryTypeUnknown,
    HBIntineraryTypeDeleted,
} HBIntineraryType;
```

and want to store it along with some other variables using the nscoding protocol

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       _name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
       // todo decode enum object
    }
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:@"name"];
    // todo encode enum object
}
```

What coder method do i use to decode and encode this kind of enum?

Comment: `decodeInt`/`encodeInt` (with some casting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking the representation of `enum`s can vary.  When working with Objective-C, you should use [the `NS_ENUM` macro](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) to be sure of which type is used to represent the enumeration.  There's more background in [this article](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/enum-num-num/).

Comment: This is the drawback of putting links as answer. You can never tell when they would start showing 404 :(

Comment: Most blog articles from Big Nerd Ranch were moved. Here is the new url: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/enum-num-num/